# the_editor() function

Tags: plugin-development, tinymce, editor

I'm writing a WordPress plug-in that requres user input, so I thought I'd try and use the default WordPress rich-text-editor. Firstly so as not to have to include a text editor in my plug-in when WordPress already has one, and secondly so it's more seamless for the user.

I literally just want the default editor, nothing changed or customised about it.

The problem is, I can't get it to work without errors, and there is little to no documentation on the `the_editor()` function.

At the moment I have this where my textbox should be:

```
<?php  
the_editor( $content, $id = 'content', $prev_id = 'title', $media_buttons = true, $tab_index = 2 );  
?>
```

And the editor appears, but with errors. For example the Visual/HTML looks broken, and the media buttons do nothing. I mean, you click them and nothing happens.

[Example here](http://img221.imageshack.us/img221/3177/wordpressi.png)

Comment: You can shorten that function a lot, like so: `the_editor( $content, 'content', 'title', true, 2 );` -- so long as `$content` is defined.

Answer (score 2):

Since this was posted, the [wp_editor() function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor) has been created. This is the correct way to include TinyMCE in a theme or plugin. Better yet, its Codex page (linked above) is much better and there are some pretty good tutorials out there.